# flexible alternative to NSTokenField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstokenfield

I am trying to customize an `NSTokenField` and after trying several hours I realized that `NSTokenField` is not customizable enough (at least using public methods).
Do you know an alternative to `NSTokenField` which can be easily customized?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? You haven't explained why `NSTokenField` is inadequate for your needs.

Comment: Indeed. I also find `NSTokenField` terrible for customization. There is no built-in way to detect token clicks, customize token appears, etc. I am looking for something like finder / mail tokens, like this http://f.cl.ly/items/062T0Y0P0m3K1N2N2T2P/Screen%20Shot%202012-01-01%20at%209.43.44%20PM.png

Comment: I also use NSTokenField , and need to select is when user click on of the suggested text. is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

How about subclassing `NSTokenField` and/or `NSTokenFieldCell`?

You could use `tokenizingCharacterSet` in conjonction with NSString's `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to get a list of tokens and then draw them however you'd like.

You'd also be able to completely respond to mouse events however you'd like (via NSCell methods for [Tracking the Mouse](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000074-SW48))

Answer (score 1):

Been there, done that and eventually ended up writing a NSTokenField replacement from scratch. It is available on [github](https://github.com/taktik/TKTokenField) if you want to have a look or use it in your project.